# Trying to generating QR in laravel but get error Use of undefined constant

Tags: laravel, qr-code

I am trying to pass code to generate a QR using chart.googleapis.com but I get **Use of undefined constant**

I can successfully do it here https://staging.veev.app/events/39 but I am having no luck doing it here https://staging.veev.app/groups/2/Young%20Professionals%20LA. Below is the code.

curl_close($ch);
$result = json_decode($result, true);

```
return $this->_loadView('client.pages.group')->with('group', $result);

    $this->data['group'] = $result;
    $group = $this->data['group'];
   $group_data = array(
        'prefix' => 'veev-groups',
        'version' => 1,
        'group_id' => $group['id'],
        'group_name' => $group['name'],
        //'group_name' => $group['result'],
        //'merchant_id' => $group['merchant_id'],
        'type' => 'groups',
        'webpage' => $this->site_baseurl.'/groups/'.$group_id
    );

    $group_data = array_values($group_data);
    $group_data = join("|||", $group_data);

    $this->data['page_name'] = $group['name'];
    $this->data['qr_srctest'] = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=250x250&chld=H%207C0&chl=' . $group_data;

    return $this->_loadView('client.pages.group')->with('group', $result);
```

Comment: Could you check the line number of the last code execution in the stack trace to better understand where is the bug, and also post the stacktrace, so we better understand why, because I don't see any use of constants in this code.

Comment: Use of what undefined constant? Where? Please copy-paste the full error msg, not just this small part of it.

Comment: @ettdro I tried posting full code but the moderator "Bhargav Rao♦" deleted it.

Comment: It was deleted because you posted it as an answer, even though it was not an answer.  If you have more information to add to your question, edit your question.  I suggest adding the full, copy-pasted text of the error - the part you have quoted is not enough to tell us anything.  Lastly, there are no "moderators" here, just users like you and me, with varying levels of experience.  Please take a few minutes and have a look through the help center, eg starting with [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: This is useful but a nightmare to use. Here is the code.